# sqlalchemy root password with @ , show error (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '16535@localhost' ([Errno 11003]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

code

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:Sakura%s@16535@localhost:3306/'+coin[x])
```

error

```
exc
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '16535@localhost' ([Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed)")
```

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[From the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting-using-uri-or-key-value-pairs.html#connecting-using-uri):

> **Important**
>
> Percent encoding must be used for reserved characters in the elements of the URI-like string. For example, if you specify a string that includes the @ character, the character must be replaced by %40. If you include a zone ID in an IPv6 address, the % character used as the separator must be replaced with %25.

So the quick answer is to replace the @ symbol with %40. In general you can encode a string in a URI-safe manner as follows, working in Python:

```py
import urllib.parse

encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(unencoded)
```